# Natural transformation $\mathbb{A}^n \setminus \{ 0 \} \to X$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, functors, natural-transformations

Let $\text{Ring}$ the category of commutative ring and $\text{Set}$ the category of set.

Denote by $\Omega : \text{Ring} \to \text{Set}$, the functor $R \mapsto \{ \text{Ideal of $R$} \}$, for a ring morphisme $\phi : R \to R'$, the induce map is $\Omega(\phi)(I) = \langle \phi(I) \rangle$ (the ideal of $R'$ generated by the image of $I$ by $\phi$.

Denote by $\mathbb{A}^n \setminus \{ 0 \}$ the functor define by $R \mapsto \{ x \in R^n \mid \langle x \rangle =R \}$, so the set of all $n$-tuple that generate the ideal $R$ of $R$.

I'm trying to descrybe ***all*** the natural transformation $\mathbb{A}^n \setminus \{ 0 \} \to \Omega$.

For an ideal $I$ of $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, i can create a natural transformation $\chi_I : \mathbb{A}^n \to \Omega$,  where $\mathbb{A}^n$ is the functor $R \mapsto R^n$ because $\mathbb{A}^n$ is represented by $(\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dots,x_n], (x_1,\dots,x_n))$ and the Yoneda lemma.

Next i can restriction $\chi_I$ to $\mathbb{A}^n \setminus \{ 0\}$. I have no idea if all natural transformation come in this way ?
thx

Comment: What do you mean by "the" natural transformation here? A priori there are many. Which one do you want?

Comment: $\mathbb{A}^n \setminus \{ 0 \}$ and $\Omega$ are two functor from $\text{Ring}$ to $\text{Set}$ and i mean Natural transformation between this two functors. So i collection of map $f_R : (\mathbb{A}^n \setminus \{0 \})(R) \to \Omega(R)$ compatible with the morphism $\phi : R \to R'$.

Comment: ah ok i see, not "the unique", i mean "all the " sorry i'm french :D

Comment: Ah, I see. The only natural transformations I know how to write down are the ones you just described, that factor through $\mathbb{A}^n$. I don't know if this is all of them. Maybe you could try writing down an affine cover of $\mathbb{A}^n \setminus \{ 0 \}$?

Comment: Yes it's one way (but  i don't finish). An other idea, let $\chi : \mathbb{A}^n \setminus \{ 0 \} \to \Omega$,  consider the ring $B = \mathbb{Z}[X_1,\dots,X_n,U_1,\dots,U_n] / \langle 1- \sum X_i U_i \rangle$ with the point $(x_1,\dots,x_n) \in (\mathbb{A}^n \setminus \{ 0 \}(B)$, We get an ideal $I = \chi_{B}(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ of $B$, perhaps if i consider $J= \mathbb{Z}[X_1,\dots,X_n] \cap I$ that give something intereting ...

Comment: Isn't $\Omega$ the classifier of closed subschemes? So a morphism $S \to \Omega$ for any scheme $S$ should be the set of closed subschemes of $S$.

Comment: Yes i think, $\Omega$ is the closed subschemes classifier : forall $Y \subset X$ closed there is a natural transformation $\chi : X \to \Omega$ s.t $\chi^{-1}(0)  = Y$.